# Setting the working directory in R when you've tried everything and it still won't work

Tags: r, directory

I cannot set a working directory in R no matter what I do and I do not know what could be the problem... I've tried writing scripts with functions ( e.g `setwd()`, changing the slashes to face forward for the location of the file i am trying to access), and I have also tried setting the working directory through the r studio files tab on the bottom right window.

Comment: Hello, sir @OlebengMogane, it would really be a big help if you add more details. Add the codes you have tried to the post and include as well the errors if there are any. This way we can try to figure out the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does using a .rproj file work? https://martinctc.github.io/blog/rstudio-projects-and-working-directories-a-beginner's-guide/

Answer (score 1):

EDITED 10/15/2023 with suggestions from @Ben Bolker, thanks!

I know you said you have tried some stuff but I'll spell everything out here for clarity and reference of others. The procedure you typed out is the correct one and RStudio should be setting your working directory. If you aren't getting error messages, it is likely working and just not saying so explicitly. If you are getting errors, then please edit your original post to include any output after you attempt to set the working directory.

There are a few methods to set working directory in RStudio:

1. Set through the RStudio GUI (point-and-click): [see instructions here](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces-in-the-RStudio-IDE)
2. By running `base::setwd()` in the R console: [see help page here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html)

To set a working directory with `base::setwd()` you should specify a full, absolute file path (in quotes - that is easy to miss). So for example, if I wanted to set working directory as my Documents folder on a Windows system I would use the following:

```
base::setwd("C:\\Users\\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\\Documents")

# or

base::setwd("C:/Users/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/Documents")

# or to choose file with GUI

base::setwd(file.choose())
```

Comment: except that you should use double backslashes for a Windows path (or, better, use forward slashes since they will work on any system)

Comment: or `setwd(file.choose())`

Comment: @BenBolker Correct - my syntax was messed up, I edited my original answer to fix this, thanks!